# Block callee number while dialling through application

Tags: android

I have a requirement wherein the user would be calling a user through the application. On calling, the user should either not be able to view the callee's number or the number should be masked so that the real number is not displayed. So for ex. if the user calls Mr. X (say the real phone number of Mr.X is 123), he should either see a masked number something like 345 or he should not be able to view the number at all.

Could anyone suggest if this can actually be done and if yes how this could be implemented on Android ? Also can this be done using cloud services like Twilio ?

Comment: I sincerely hope that this is impossible. Whether you like it or not, phone owners have a right to know where their phone is calling.

Comment: While not trying to spark a debate because I inherently agree, some advocates would say that ONLY the phone's OWNER has that right. More importantly, possession does not indicate ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Naveen,

Yes, this is absolutely possible. However, it requires some analysis and tricksy work on your part. First, you must insure that the devices in question may have the Phone Dialer replaced by another Phone Dialer Application (yours). Second, you must write your own Phone Dialer that would obstruct the viewing of said numbers from the display. This may require you to build a custom ROM to replace on the device.

Regarding implementation, the question is too broad to have a clear concise answer on here. You would probably address it in parts. The information above should get you started though. Mind you, it is important to know that each device has its own limitations and requirements based upon the ROM that is installed upon them by the manufacturer and provider. This means that you may have to do a ton of research.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic